# fread() from binary file then printf streamed string - not working

Tags: clang, fwrite, fread

C Lang Newb:  My goal:  Using a character stream using getchar() into an array and write array to a binary file, and then retrieve binary file into array and output string on console.  I was successful with all parts except the output to console.

Call to function:

```
    if (c == '6')
                loadDoc();
```

Write file function:

```
 int saveDoc(char document[MAXSIZE], int size){

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("document.bin", "wb");
    

    if (!f) {
        printf("Error during writing to file !\n");
    }
    else{
        
        fwrite(&document, sizeof(document), size, f);
        fclose(f);
    }

return 0;
}
```

Read file function:

```
char loadDoc(){
    
    char buffer[1000];

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("document.bin", "rb");

        if (!f) {
            printf("Error during reading file !\n");
        }
        else {
            printf("Size of buffer: %d\n", sizeof(buffer));
            fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, f);
            printf("File cpntents: \n %s\n", buffer);
            fclose(f);
        }
            
return 0;

}
```

Output:

```
********************
1) Start New Document:
2) View Document:
3) Edit Document:
4) Delete Document:
5) Save Document:
6) Load Document:
7) Exit
********************
6
Size of buffer: 1000
File cpntents:
 @p@
```

When I open file in notebook, actual content of file is:

```
@p@     &       P                     ÿÿÿÿ&   ðýb     µ@      ú ~ù         3               ÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ1       þb     B@             3                            è@             3        =A
```

The input entered into file saved and expected output to console with file is read:

```
This code isn't working as expected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct working solution in GCC:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void save_to_binary_file(const char* file_name, const char* text_data)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "wb"); 
    if(file == NULL)
        printf("Failed to open file %s\n", file_name);
    if(fwrite(text_data, sizeof(char), strlen(text_data) + 1, file) != (strlen(text_data) + 1))
        puts("Failed to write all text data\n");
    fclose(file);
}

char* load_binary_file_as_text(const char* file_name)
{
    FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "rb"); 
    if(file == NULL)
        printf("Failed to open file %s\n", file_name);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END); 
    size_t file_size_in_bytes = ftell(file);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char* read_buffer = (char*)malloc(file_size_in_bytes);
    if(fread(read_buffer, 1, file_size_in_bytes, file) != file_size_in_bytes)
        puts("Failed to read all the bytes\n"); 
    fclose(file);
    return read_buffer;
}

int main()
{
    save_to_binary_file("Data.data", "ABCD"); 
    char* buffer = load_binary_file_as_text("Data.data");
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply... i've seen many of these examples.  I'm learning the language and used a deconstructed structure to try and understand the parts, how they work and what they are doing... I'm not seeing why my code isn't working... i don't need the code written for me, but perhaps a pointer... thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the '&' in the fwrite() call.  Removed it and works as expected.